# How do I Install external APKs necessary for my app in the Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, installation, apk, external-application

I need to rely on external app (Barcode scanner in my case). The eclipse emulator crashes when I try to download it from within the emulator itself.

- Is there a way to download it using the emulator?
- Or Is there a way to directly install the APK and make it available for my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the emulator from eclipse.

Check to see if the device is detected using :`>adb devices`

I ran the `adb install foo.apk`

This installed the APK in the emulator.

- If the Command prompt says no AVD, you will need to create one `>android create avd -n <avd-name> -t 2`
- Installing the apk in the tools is considered the best practice

Answer (score 0):

You could download it to your computer, copy it to the sdcard, then install a file manager in your phone, I use ASTRO, browse to the apk in ASTRO and open it, this will ask you to install it. Before you can install it, you need to set your phone to allow Unknown Sources (i.e. non-Market apps) to be installed (Settings -> Applications).